# What is the programatically way of upgrading (discovery) stm32's firmware? (replacing the ST loader util)

Tags: usb, upgrade, stm32, bootloader, firmware

I am trying to upgrade the firmware on a STM32F407G (Discovery board).

I am  already able to run the bootloader on the board (as checked with the st utility to upgrade the firmware using the dfu mode).

Now, I want to create my own app to upgrade the firmware of the device, how can I replicate the functionality of the ST's SW? Any recommendation?

I want to be able to do so, if possible, by connecting the device with the micro-usb port.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

ST Application Note *[AN3156 USB DFU protocol used in the STM32 bootloader](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/6a/17/92/02/58/98/45/0c/CD00264379.pdf/files/CD00264379.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00264379.pdf)* describes the protocol.